# Has color vision deficiency ever contributed to any incidents in aviation history?

Tags: accidents, medical, accident-investigation, easa, eu

I would like to know if there are any official reports pointing Color Vision Deficiency (CVD) as a major contributing cause of an air accident/incident. Not only related to flying but also maintenance or ATC for instace.

So far, I have only come across with [FedEx flight 1478](https://www.ntsb.gov/news/events/Pages/Collision_with_Trees_on_Final_Approach_FedEx_flight_1478_Boeing_727-232_N497FE_Tallahassee_Florida_July_26_2002.aspx), in which a CVD F/O misjudged the PAPI lights. However, the report does not point how severe was the F/O's deficiency (all crew survived the accident). And more important is that the Captain and Flight Engineer (with normal color vision) could neither detect the wrong glidepath.

My final goal is to research the topic of color-blindness in aviation with real case instances and hopefully draw some conclusions about the actual impact of this disease in aviation for candidate's medical certification.

Comment: CVD is only disqualifying for night flying or "color signal control". I don't think this is one of the regulations that is "written in blood" as many others are. Many flying cues are by color and if you can't distinguish colors, you need restrictions.

Comment: Things in general are so much more flexible now.  In Canada at least you can hold a Cat 1 while blind in one eye and even with Type 1 diabetes (albeit with a lot of restrictions).

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, there is no doubt that aviation jobs require color discrimination capabilities. The thing is that CVD varies greatly among candidates. The issue here is where to draw the line where safety is not compromised. My own experience has shown me that values are kept very conservative using empyrical tests (such as Ishihara test plate) and I am afraid that a more pragmatic approach is missing. For instance, creating simulator scenarios where color discrimination is at stake for safety.

Comment: Have you read [how they test for CVD](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources/health-conditions/vision/color-restriction-removal)? A flight test is part of a class 1/2 medical (which is required for commercial purposes). Maybe we aren't talking about the same country? A "color vision medical flight test" is an *actual flight test* with a medical examiner... If you pass that, you get your license without restrictions. If you fail *you get your license with restrictions*...

Comment: @RonBeyer I live in Spain, so I tend to think in terms of EASA's regulations. I know that FAA regulations can grant a color vision waiver which implies a "color vision medical flight test". Sadly, we don't have that in Europe. Here, a CVD candidate can get his 1/2 medical certification restricted to fly only under VFR in day time. For someone who wants to have fun with his PPL, this might not seem a problem. But I greatly doubt that any airline would hire a pilot with such restriction.

Comment: @ppinto Please add country-specific tags to your question if you want country-specific answers.

Comment: One of the flaws in this line of questioning is that until recently most regulators have largely prohibited pilots with CVD from flying, you certainly won't find 2 pilots in an airliner who both have CVD. This is slowly changing so this question is worth revisiting in maybe 15 years time.

Comment: Have you thought about this from a maintenance perspective? Maintenance personnel can't be colourblind at the places I've worked. The reasons given to me are because many aircraft parts including electrical components are identified only by different colour bands... Wires identified by colour... Identifying test patterns on screens...

Comment: @Craig I am not sure about the point you are trying to make. But let me explain that the post talks about candidates with Color Vision Deficiency and not full Color Blindness. Obviously, people that lack any color channel would face serious problems in the aviation jobs. But that's not necessary the case for CVD. This kind often struggle with colors that are really close in terms of hue and saturation and, as you would know, colors in aviation are well-separated hue/saturation coded. What I'm trying to adress is whrere the limits in CVD should be impossed based on real data.

Comment: @ppinto my point is that an incident could be caused by incorrect maintenance because the wrong component was fitted or something like that. Interpretation type issues have caused accidents before, notably the time there was confusion between the words "expired" and "empty" with regards to oxy cannisters put in a cargo hold, which then caught fire. It wouldn't be a stretch to imagine that there could be a colour interpretation example around somewhere. Just can't think of any right now

Comment: @Craig thank you for your clarification. This hypothetical color interpretation incident that you are considereing is exactly what I'm looking for. I would really appreciate if you could bring any real case where this has happened. I will do my research trying to find incidents not only related to pilot color vision but also for maintenance and ATC. I will expand the scope of the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

In response to two NTSB safety recommendations, the FAA stated that it has only identified three accidents involving pilots with valid medical qualifications in which color vision deficiency (CVD) was cited as a contributing cause.

1. As you mention above, on July 26, 2002, a Federal Express Boeing 727-200F crashed during a visual approach to Tallahassee Regional Airport in nighttime visual meteorological conditions. The three crew members were seriously injured and the airplane was destroyed in the crash, which the NTSB attributed to “the captain’s and first officer’s failure to establish and maintain a proper glide path.” Because the first officer was flying the plane at the time of the crash, the NTSB cited as one of several contributing factors “the first officer’s color vision deficiency" which interfered with his ability to discern the red and white lights of the precision approach path indicator (PAPI).
2. On Aug. 29, 1992, an incident occurred in which the pilot of a Mooney 20F with “a waiver for partial color blindness to red and green” landed on a closed runway that was marked with orange crosses in the dirt 50 ft beyond each end. The pilot’s “limited ability to detect the orange-colored marking” was cited as a contributing factor.
3. One incident involved a Navy F4J lost on Aug. 5, 1980, “when a severely color deficient pilot failed to interpret correctly the colored navigation lights of other aircraft in the area, leading to the false impression of a collision.”

Regarding the severity of the FO's color blindness from FedEx flight 1478, records indicate that he passed all color vision tests during his 16 years as a U.S. Navy pilot but failed a test administered during an FAA medical evaluation in 1995. This failed test indicated that he had a mild red-green deficiency. The FAA issued a first-class medical certificate with a statement of demonstrated ability (SODA), based on his years as a Navy pilot and the results of his Navy color vision tests. He was issued this SODA on all subsequent medical examinations.

After the 2002 crash, the first officer passed the Farnsworth Lantern (FALANT) color vision test, which was designed to differentiate between those with mild red-green deficiencies, who pass the test, and others with more significant red-green deficiencies, who fail. He also passed a light-gun-signal test administered by an FAA medical examiner. However, he failed seven other red-green color vision tests and was determined to have a “severe congenital deuteranomaly” — a red-green deficiency that is the most common color vision defect.

Hope this helps.

References: Werfelman, L. (2008, December). Color deficient?[PDF] *Aero Safety World*, 38-41. Flight Safety Foundation. Retrieved from:http://www.flightsafety.org/asw/dec08/asw_dec08_p38-41.pdf